# How to make a page visible using a variable on another page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a blazor application where I have the main window and other files which are the child windows.

I'm looking for a way for the main window button to open the child window, but even though the `EnableConf` value is true, the window won't open, I tried using `StateHasChanged()` and it still doesn't work.

**CheckState.cs**

```
public class CheckState {
    public bool EnableConf { get; set; } = false;
}
```

**MainWindow.cs in MainWindow()**

```
Collect.AddScoped<CheckState>();
```

**Conf.razor**

```
@inject AppBlaz.CheckState CheckState

if(CheckState.EnableConf) {
    <style>
    ...
    </style>
    ...
    <button @onclick="()=> CloseConf()">
    ...
    
}

@code {
    private void CloseConf() {
        CheckState.EnableConf = false;
    }
}
```

**main.razor**

```
@inject AppBlaz.CheckState CheckState
...
<button @onclick="()=> OpenConf()">
...

@code { 
    private void OpenConf() {
        CheckState.EnableConf = true;
    }
}
```

The child window close button works perfectly, the only problem is that the main window cannot open the child window.

Does anyone know how I can make this work correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming that somewhere in the `main.razor` you actually have placed the child window component (Conf.razor) to be hidden or displayed and there is no java script / third party lib that popups this window:

Add

```cs
[Parameter]
public bool CheckState {get; set;}
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<bool> CheckStateChanged { get; set; }
```

to your Conf.razor. Use this property as replacement for `CheckState.EnableConf` - if needed, then in  `OnAfterRender()` override assign value to new property from currently used service (`CheckState`).

`if(CheckState.EnableConf)` becames `if(CheckState)`.

In `main.razor`:
Repeat the above, but ommit `[parameter]` attribute for `CheckState` and drop whole `CheckStateChanged` including the `[Parameter]`.
In place where the `Conf.razor` is initialized / put into actual ui code add
`<Conf @Bind-CheckState=CheckState />` - now you will pass this newly created property down the line to child window.

In `OpenConf()` method change the newly created `CheckState` parameter instead of / in addition to `CheckState.EnableConf`.
`CloseConf` now should re

This should trigger the UI update. In case of emergency, add `StateHasChanged()` at the end of `OpenConf()` method.

Again, this should work (more or less, I typed in from memory) for standard blazor components.

Comment: After some corrections I managed to make it work, but I wanted to ask something.
Is it possible to keep these variables in a different file like I used **CheckState.cs**?

Comment: If you just want another file, then I would go with code-ui blazor separation. Just create new file in the same dir where you have, for example, `main.razor` and name it `main.razor.cs`. Content of this new file would be a **partial** class named `main` in your case. Then move the code from `@code` block from your razor file to the new file, ofc without actual `@code` block. Mind that the constructor injection does not work for such classes yet. You will have to use `[Inject]` attribute above properties you want to inject. Duplicated injections can be removed from `main.razor` file.

Comment: Example:
[Gui](https://github.com/quain24/ScanApp/blob/master/ScanApp/Components/Table/SCTable.razor) and 
[Code](https://github.com/quain24/ScanApp/blob/master/ScanApp/Components/Table/SCTable.razor.cs) files in the **same** directory - this should help You out.